# "Send Test" buttons greyed out inactive

Tags: civimail, joomla, 4.6.2

When "SEND TEST" buttons are greyed out there is no notification as to what is missing from required fields to be NOT NULL. By default if "Opt-Out" token is not included in the message the "Opt-Out" response is left NULL but is still a required field that cannot be left empty. Choosing the only default brings all the buttons active. Please advise?

Answer (score 2):

- There shouldn't be any connection between the "Opt-Out"/"Unsubscribe" token and the field "Responses: Opt-Out Message". Both are required.
- If the "Opt-Out" token (or "Unsubscribe" token) is missing, then you should get a very loud error message. (The token is generally provided as part of a header, footer, or message template, so that you don't have to put it in explicitly.)
- The field "Responses: Opt-Out Message" should be filled in by default. If it's not, then perhaps someone removed the default. Try navigating to "Mailings => Headers, Footers, and Automated Messages". Edit one of the "OptOut" messages and set it as default.

Comment: CiviCRM will allow it to pass with one *or* the other or both tokens. And, a little "Duh!" on the default Opt-Out message. You are correct. And, thank you for the patch. Great work!

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple more situations that the greyed out button can appear which may be less than obvious

- if there is no Resubscribe Msg set on the Response tab (no alert is currently provided
- if you put in a Subject, but then decide to switch to using a Template that has no Subject then the one you added gets wiped