# Send Test and Next not clickable (greyed) due to missing value in reply_id field (i think)

Tags: civimail

Similar to this [question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3385/mailing-send-test-button-not-a-button) and [this one](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2505/send-test-buttons-greyed-out-inactive) but different issues. All required fields and tokens are filled in. But db is showing Null for reply_id field, whereas all earlier mailings have an '8' in that field. I can't see if this is settable via the UI and am unsure why this would either now be required, or the default is NULL. This site recently upgraded from 4.4.19 to 4.6.8 with no warnings related to this afaik.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the answer, or a better identification of the problem.

I see that in Headers, Footers etc Auto-responder ID is '8' but is not set as default.

Not sure if setting it to default, and saving and reopening my mailing resulted in button being clickable or if that was the one I edited in DB.

Will have to look in to whether someone turned that default off or it is was a minor glitch in the upgrading.

Comment: Is this something that 'is' settable via the UI and I am being blind? Should an error msg be showing on the civimail screen if no reply_id is set?

Comment: In my case, I had a site where the Auto-responder (from Administer > CiviMail > Headers, Footers, and Automatic Messages) was disabled when the first mailing was created (actually, all of the pre-configured messages/headers/footers were disabled). Enabling all of them and setting as default didn't fix the already created mailing (the "Send Test" and "Next" buttons were still disabled) but everything worked properly in a new mailing, created after enabling pre-configured messages/headers/footers.

Comment: and hit this again - in this case client set up a Xmas Auto Reponder. And concur that setting the Standard one as Default doesn't resolve for existing Draft Mailings but does for future ones - note these values are in civicrm_mailing_component table

Comment: and the missing value that affects the draft ones is civicrm_mailing.reply_id which appears to not get reset when the Draft is saved